# Dollar Sign is not declared

Tags: javascript

https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/sL7lKBrbXvQbhRGBf54wrQ/

My project is about generating random sentences. How do I make it from here, so that the program picks a random sentence from the index, and displays it on the screen? Please help.

It says that the '$ is not declared'.

Eddie

[My coding picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlscG.png)

Comment: `$` in your code means that you are calling some jQuery. Did you load jQuery?

Comment: Add jquery library...that's it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include jQuery in your HTML file like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script
```